# How to structure controllers to match nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

My app is becoming very sensitive to context, as far as nested resources are concerned.

For example, let's say my app is a librarian app, and I might have routes like this:

```
resources :books
resources :libraries do
  resources :books
end
```

And I want it to be such that if you visit `/books`, that you see books related to you, the logged in user. Be it books you've checked out or books you've favorited or what have you.

But when you visit `/libraries/:id/books`, you should see books related to that library.

Now, that's pretty easy to do in the controller:

```
def index
  if params[:library_id]
    @library = Library.find(params[:library_id])
    @books = @library.books
  else
    @books = current_user.books
  end
end
```

However, this pattern is repeated several times throughout my app (think if I wanted to have books nested under authors or publishers!) My controller can get very complex. It gets even harder if I want to have different views for each context.

So, I'd like to have two books controllers. One in the root namespace, and one namespaced under libraries.

That's fine. I've already constructed `BooksController` and `Library::BooksController`. However, I'm running into problems setting up sensible routes.

I first thought I could just specify the namespace:

```
resources :books
resources :libraries do
  namespace :library do
    resources :books
  end
end
```

But that breaks the existing routes, looking like `/libraries/:id/library/books`

So, I tried passing `path: false` to the namespace, which fixes the route, but makes named routes and polymorphic routes very cumbersome.

I'd expect in order to visit `/libraries/123/books`, I could do:

```
link_to "See books", [@library, :books] # -or- 
link_to "See books", library_books_path(@library)
```

However, since we've added the namespace, routes are pretty bulky now:

```
link_to "See books", [@library, :library, :books] # -or- 
link_to "See books", library_library_books_path(@library)
```

So, is there a more conventional way to structure controllers that make sense with nested resources? Is there a better way to construct my routes?

**UPDATE**

I've got expected results by adding `as: false` to the namespace declaration like so:

```
resources :books
resources :libraries do
  namespace :library, path: false, as: false do
    resources :books
  end
end
```

And H-man noted that you can specify a controller on each resource. However, that doesn't feel right as management of a large number of routes could get out of control.

So both solutions *work*, but is there a more conventional way to approach this?

**UPDATE #2**

I've landed on using `#defaults` from `ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::Scoping` which allows you to send arguments straight to `#scope` without a bunch of other interfering logic. I like this better since rather than setting negatives, I'm setting positive configuration:

```
resources :books
resources :libraries do
  defaults module: :libraries
    resources :books
  end
end
```

However, the question still stands if I'm following good convention... This still doesn't feel 100% right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using scoped modules:

```
resources :books

scope module: :libraries do
  resources :libraries do
    resources :books
  end
end
```

Then you should have these sorts of helpers available to get to the index actions (for example):

```
books_path == [:books]
library_books_path(@library) == [@library, :books]
```

I get torn on whether or not the `libraries` resource should be under the scoped module, but most of the time it makes sense to do so. Pretend that you want to take that chunk out and put it in a gem later (even if that's not your plan). That helps to draw the line on what goes in each scoped module.

Comment: yeah, scopes still muddy up the route helpers

Comment: Are you sure? I swear I've solved a problem similar to yours using this kind of code. Or I could be misreading your question.

Comment: No, you;re right, I'm sorry, it adds into the path. You have to do `path: false` to maintain the same route. I've got an edit about to go up

Comment: Actually, you were even more right than I thought. Using `#scope` with a module specified actually does exactly what I hoped. However, just declaring `scope :libraries` shoves stuff into the path

Comment: Hooray! Figuring out how to organize controllers has bugged me for a long time, so I'm glad I could share my solution with someone. Rock on.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specify a different controller for the nested route, you can always do this:

```
resources :books
resources :libraries do
  resources :books, controller: 'libraries/books'
end
```

That way, you can have two controllers:

- app/controllers/books_controller.rb
- app/controllers/libraries/books_controller.rb

What I usually do in this case, is let each controller controller handle the scoping, and put the shared functionality in a concern. i.e:

app/controllers/books_controller.rb

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  include BooksControllerConcern

private
  def book_scope
    current_user.books
  end
end
```

app/controllers/libraries/books_controller.rb

```
class Libraries::BooksController < ApplicationController
  include BooksControllerConcern

private
  def book_scope
    Book.find_by(library_id: params[:library_id])
  end
end
```

concern:

```
module BooksControllerConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def index
    @books = book_scope.page(params[:page])
  end

  # .. other shared actions
end
```

Your routes will look like this:

- [:books] or books_path => /books
- [@library, :books] or library_books_path(@library) => /libraries/:id/books

Comment: Just a quick note: I haven't verified that my code works, but you get the point. Hope this helps.

Comment: So, it'd be nice if there were a way to set the namespace for a group of routes, though. rather than having to specify the controller on each resource.

Comment: Yes, I agree. This approach looks a tiny bit weird in the routes, but it generates the correct routes that you want and it preserves a clean folder structure.